# Caching Java 8 stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have a list which I perform multiple stream operations on.

```
  bobs = myList.stream()
        .filter(person -> person.getName().equals("Bob"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())

...
```

and

```
  tonies = myList.stream()
        .filter(person -> person.getName().equals("tony"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Can I not just do:

```
Stream<Person> stream = myList.stream();
```

which then means I can do:

```
  bobs = stream.filter(person -> person.getName().equals("Bob"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
  tonies = stream.filter(person -> person.getName().equals("tony"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: As you probably noticed you cannot do that. But can you explain why you want to cache the stream ?

Comment: You can't even call `.filter` on the same stream "leg" more than once (or any other operation, for that matter), because a Stream is a "pipe", and any operation (final or not) appends a new leg to the pipe, "sealing" the original pipe output; you then have to work with the output of the new pipe leg, and so on. This also looks like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) question. You should really explain what you're actually trying to do, it'll keep people from guessing and will give you the answer to your actual problem.

Comment: `Map<Boolean,List<Person>> map = stream.filter(p -> p.getName().matches("Bob|tony")) .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p -> p.getName().equals("Bob"))); bobs = map.get(true); tonies = map.get(false);`

Comment: @Holger your proposed solution restrict the OP to binary input. Nevermind, it is still favorable in a binary context.

Comment: @marsouf it’s easy to change to use `groupingBy` instead of `partitioningBy`, if desired. But as long as it’s a binary choice, `partitioningBy` has a performance advantage. The more important point is to identify “how can I stream twice?” as an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/242352), which will help solving even entirely different future problems by starting with the right mindset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO, you can't. One `Stream` can only be use one time  It will throw below error when you will try to reuse:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:229)
```

As per [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once.

But a neat solution to your query will be to use Stream Suplier. It looks like below:

```
Supplier<Stream<Person>> streamSupplier = myList::stream;
bobs = streamSupplier.get().filter(person -> person.getName().equals("Bob"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
tonies = streamSupplier.get().filter(person -> person.getName().equals("tony"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But again, every `get` call will return a new stream.

Comment: No advantage to `streamSupplier.get()` over `myList.stream()`. It's longer.

Comment: keep the name smaller and it will be shorter _st.get()_ vs _myList.stream()_ :D Anyways I just shared an Idea with OP how he can do what he is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you can do in your case is generate dynamic stream pipelines. Assuming that the only variable in your pipeline is the name of the person that you filter by.

We can represent this as a `Function<String, Stream<Person>>` as in the following :

```
final Function<String, Stream<Person>> pipelineGenerator = name -> persons.stream().filter(person -> Objects.equals(person.getName(), name));

final List<Person> bobs = pipelineGenerator.apply("bob").collect(Collectors.toList());

final List<Person> tonies = pipelineGenerator.apply("tony").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, doc says:

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal
>   stream operation) only once.

But you can use a single stream by filtering all elements you want once and then group them the way you need:

```
Set<String> names = ...; // construct a sets containing bob, tony, etc
Map<String,List<Person>> r = myList.stream()
                                   .filter(p -> names.contains(p.getName())
                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName);
List<Person> tonies = r.get("tony");
List<Person> bobs = r.get("bob");
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned a given stream should be operated upon *only once*.

I can understand the "idea" of caching a reference to an object if you're going to refer to it more than once, or to simply avoid creating more objects than necessary.

However, you should not be concerned when invoking `myList.stream()` every time you need to query again as creating a stream, in general, is a cheap operation.